# how to make an autocomplete combobox in javafx 2.x using modern .fxml and controller.java

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx-2, fxml

how to make a similer autocomplete combobox in javafx 2.x using modern .fxml and controller.java as this one is made

http://blog.ngopal.com.np/2011/07/04/autofill-textbox-with-filtermode-in-javafx-2-0-custom-control/

above mentioned demo is messy and hard to configure and be independant (requires some jars)

Comment: click [here][1] AutoComplete ComboBox in JavaFX

http://stackoverflow.com/a/20282301/1315392

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20282301/1315392

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensemlbe -- a sample included into the standard set has similar control. It's opensourced, so you can download it and take a look into sources:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/javafx-samples-2158687.html

take a look at `SearchBox.java`

Comment: nice, thanks. but SearchBox.java is hard to customize. I just need to give an observablelist or List or ArrayList. isnt there a simple control to use or customize? or how can I customize this one easily?

Comment: cant it be configured to use a simple list for searching?

Comment: thanks. thats the closest I can get

Answer (score 0):

May be i am late but the link that you posted is now already compatible with the FXML as well just add

to your fxml and also add the import directive in fxml.

Test Source Code is in Github: 
https://github.com/privatejava/javafx-autocomplete-field/blob/master/src/test/FXML.fxml#L12