# Auto select item on JavaFX ComboBox after KeyPress

Tags: java, combobox, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

i have a ComboBox with the following items:

```
Mateus
Marina
Josefina
```

In swing, if i type a part of a name, e.g, 'MAR', it selects the item 'Marina', but in JavaFX, id toes nothing. The user have to search through the items by scrolling or using arrow keys (both searching the items one by one).
How can i get something like this to work in JavaFX ComboBox?

Comment: Maybe you could use an [autocomplete TextField from ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/) instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaFX - Filtered ComboBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010619/javafx-filtered-combobox)

Comment: actually it would be better if i had a comboBox because the user needs to see what options he can choose without spelling anything.

Comment: @MateusViccari AutomComplete TextField has the feature of showing all the options without typing anything !

Comment: Alright, i already have controls fx in my project but i dont know how to create the components through fxml, and found nothing on their site... What am i missing?