# Finding an element on a combobox which has too many data on JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a combobox that has around 90 elements in it. In some applications when you select the combobox you can type and find the element easily. But when i tried it on javaFx it didn't work.Is there a way to do this? Because now user needs to scroll down which sucks due to number of elements in the combobox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at this https://github.com/jesuino/javafx-combox-autocomplete 
 or [JavaFX - Filtered ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010619/javafx-filtered-combobox)

If not what you can have as a work around is have a text box that is bound to the observable of data in the combobox and on keypress you filter the observable