# Combobox select from search results Javafx

Tags: java, database, javafx, combobox

I need to allow a user to pick names from a database. What I have in mind is a text field that they can start to type a name into and then a dropdown will appear with a list of names that they can pick from. This is a combination of a regular text field and a combobox. I have the database side of this already handled where it takes in characters such as "Aa" and returns "Aaron", "Aardvark", and "Aaliyah". They should then only be able to select from "Aaron", "Aardvark", and "Aaliyah".

Comment: And the question is?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the answer to my question from this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20282301/6291036

I used java.net.http to pull the data from the api and converted the json to java variables. I was then able to put those variables in the combobox items.