# AutoComplete ComboBox in JavaFX without Lambda Expressions

Tags: java, lambda, combobox, javafx-8

I read [AutoComplete ComboBox in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924852/autocomplete-combobox-in-javafx) but the answer with the most upvotes uses Lambda expressions.

In my project i can't use them, so I would like to ask if someone could provide the code without lambda expressions.

Here are the two parts of the code with lambda expressions:

1)

```
comboBox.getEditor().focusedProperty().addListener(observable -> {
            if (comboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() < 0) {
                comboBox.getEditor().setText(null);
            }
        });
```

2)

```
comboBox.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, t -> comboBox.hide());
```

Comment: Every lambda expression can be converted to a anonymus class. However not being allowed  to use lambdas in javafx **8** seems to be a absurd constraint since there are classes in the API using lambdas...

Comment: I use version 7. Just wanted to tagg it under javafx-8 so people who know lamda expressions see this.

Comment: You should be able to determine how to write non-lambda implementations by looking at the documentation for the two methods:  [Observable.addListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/Observable.html#addListener-javafx.beans.InvalidationListener-) and [Node.addEventHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#addEventHandler-javafx.event.EventType-javafx.event.EventHandler-).  Assuming you are familiar with writing anonymous classes, that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IDE should be able to convert back and forth.  Below is a sample of using that in Eclipse.

1)

```
comboBox.getEditor().focusedProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
            @Override
            public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
                 if (comboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() < 0) {
                     comboBox.getEditor().setText(null);
                 }
            }
        });
```

2)

```
comboBox.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
                comboBox.hide();
            }
        });
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. I use IntelliJ and I did not found the option then?

Comment: I think the option only shows up if you have Java 8 enabled.

Answer (score 4):

If you're willing to use external libraries, you can make an autocompleting ComboBox with just a few lines of code using [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/).

```
ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
comboBox.getItems().addAll("Hello", "Hello World", "Hey");
comboBox.setEditable(true);
TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(comboBox.getEditor(), comboBox.getItems());
```

[image: controlsFX autocomplete box]