# How to prevent closing of AutoCompleteCombobox popupmenu on whitespace key press in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, filter, combobox, whitespace

I have created a AutoCompleteCombobox in JavaFX, but issue is that combobox popup closes when user presses SPACE key. I want to continue filtering with space character and prevent popup from closing.

I just want to know how can I override the event handler which handles SPACE key press.

Please help...I've been banging my head against the wall all day on this...

```
package org.fxapps;

import java.text.Normalizer;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.stage.Window;

/**
 * 
 * Uses a combobox tooltip as the suggestion for auto complete and updates the
 * combo box itens accordingly <br />
 * It does not work with space, space and escape cause the combobox to hide and
 * clean the filter ... Send me a PR if you want it to work with all characters
 * -> It should be a custom controller - I KNOW!
 * 
 * @author wsiqueir
 *
 * @param <T>
 */
public class ComboBoxAutoComplete<T> {

    private ComboBox<T> cmb;
    String filter = "";
    private ObservableList<T> originalItems;

    public ComboBoxAutoComplete(ComboBox<T> cmb) {
        this.cmb = cmb;
        originalItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList(cmb.getItems());
        cmb.setTooltip(new Tooltip());
        cmb.setOnKeyPressed(this::handleOnKeyPressed);
        cmb.setOnHidden(this::handleOnHiding);
    }

    public void handleOnKeyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        ObservableList<T> filteredList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        KeyCode code = e.getCode();

        if (code.isLetterKey()) {
            filter += e.getText();
        }
        if (code == KeyCode.BACK_SPACE && filter.length() > 0) {
            filter = filter.substring(0, filter.length() - 1);
            cmb.getItems().setAll(originalItems);
        }
        if (code == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
            filter = "";
        }
        if (filter.length() == 0) {
            filteredList = originalItems;
            cmb.getTooltip().hide();
        } else {
            Stream<T> itens = cmb.getItems().stream();
            String txtUsr = unaccent(filter.toString().toLowerCase());
            itens.filter(el -> unaccent(el.toString().toLowerCase()).contains(txtUsr)).forEach(filteredList::add);
            cmb.getTooltip().setText(txtUsr);
            Window stage = cmb.getScene().getWindow();
            double posX = stage.getX() + cmb.getBoundsInParent().getMinX();
            double posY = stage.getY() + cmb.getBoundsInParent().getMinY();
            cmb.getTooltip().show(stage, posX, posY);
            cmb.show();
        }
        cmb.getItems().setAll(filteredList);
    }

    public void handleOnHiding(Event e) {
        filter = "";
        cmb.getTooltip().hide();
        T s = cmb.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        cmb.getItems().setAll(originalItems);
        cmb.getSelectionModel().select(s);
    }

    private String unaccent(String s) {
        String temp = Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+");
        return pattern.matcher(temp).replaceAll("");
    }

}
```

And this is the test:

```
package org.fxapps;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ComboBoxAutoCompleteTest extends Application {

    private static final String[] LISTA = { "Abacate", "Abacaxi", "Ameixa", "Amora", "Araticum", "Atemoia", "Avocado",
            "Banana prata", "Caju", "Cana descascada", "Caqui", "Caqui Fuyu", "Carambola", "Cereja", "Coco verde",
            "Figo", "Figo da Índia", "Framboesa", "Goiaba", "Graviola", "Jabuticaba", "Jambo", "Jambo rosa", "Jambolão",
            "Kino (Kiwano)", "Kiwi", "Laranja Bahia", "Laranja para suco", "Laranja seleta", "Laranja serra d’água",
            "Laranjinha kinkan", "Lichia", "Lima da pérsia", "Limão galego", "Limão Taiti", "Maçã argentina",
            "Maçã Fuji", "Maçã gala", "Maçã verde", "Mamão formosa", "Mamão Havaí", "Manga espada", "Manga Haden",
            "Manga Palmer", "Manga Tommy", "Manga Ubá", "Mangostim", "Maracujá doce", "Maracujá para suco", "Melancia",
            "Melancia sem semente", "Melão", "Melão Net", "Melão Orange", "Melão pele de sapo", "Melão redinha",
            "Mexerica carioca", "Mexerica Murcote", "Mexerica Ponkan", "Mirtilo", "Morango", "Nectarina",
            "Nêspera ou ameixa amarela", "Noni", "Pera asiática", "Pera portuguesa", "Pêssego", "Physalis", "Pinha",
            "Pitaia", "Romã", "Tamarilo", "Tamarindo", "Uva red globe", "Uva rosada", "Uva Rubi", "Uva sem semente",
            "Abobora moranga", "Abobrinha italiana", "Abobrinha menina", "Alho", "Alho descascado",
            "Batata baroa ou cenoura amarela", "Batata bolinha", "Batata doce", "Batata inglesa", "Batata yacon",
            "Berinjela", "Beterraba", "Cebola bolinha", "Cebola comum", "Cebola roxa", "Cenoura", "Cenoura baby",
            "Couve flor", "Ervilha", "Fava", "Gengibre", "Inhame", "Jiló", "Massa de alho", "Maxixe", "Milho",
            "Pimenta biquinho fresca", "Pimenta de bode fresca", "Pimentão amarelo", "Pimentão verde",
            "Pimentão vermelho", "Quiabo", "Repolho", "Repolho roxo", "Tomate cereja", "Tomate salada",
            "Tomate sem acidez", "Tomate uva", "Vagem", "Agrião", "Alcachofra", "Alface", "Alface americana",
            "Almeirão", "Brócolis", "Broto de alfafa", "Broto de bambu", "Broto de feijão", "Cebolinha", "Coentro",
            "Couve", "Espinafre", "Hortelã", "Mostarda", "Rúcula", "Salsa", "Ovos brancos", "Ovos de codorna",
            "Ovos vermelhos" };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        ComboBox<String> cmb = new ComboBox<>();
        cmb.setTooltip(new Tooltip());
        cmb.getItems().addAll(LISTA);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(cmb)));
        stage.show();
        stage.setTitle("Filtrando um ComboBox");
        stage.setWidth(300);
        stage.setHeight(300);
        new ComboBoxAutoComplete<String>(cmb);
    }

}
```

I used the help of code mentioned on https://github.com/jesuino/javafx-combox-autocomplete/blob/master/src/main/java/org/fxapps/ComboBoxAutoComplete.java

I have handled all three events (key press, key release, key typed) on combobox but no solutions. I think it is being caused by key press event on combobox item list view.

Bug is mentioned on https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8087549

This is the same question as posed here (but I am unable to ask a question or make a comment on that page):
[How to prevent closing of AutoCompleteCombobox popupmenu on SPACE key press in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50013972/how-to-prevent-closing-of-autocompletecombobox-popupmenu-on-space-key-press-in-j?noredirect=1&lq=1)

There are a lot of good posts here, too (but I am not smart enough to figure out how to get any of them to work and fix this space bug!)
[AutoComplete ComboBox in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924852/autocomplete-combobox-in-javafx)

**I tried the answer/code on** [How to prevent closing of AutoCompleteCombobox popupmenu on SPACE key press in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50013972/how-to-prevent-closing-of-autocompletecombobox-popupmenu-on-space-key-press-in-j), but it either doesn't change the behavior and/or I am too stupid to make it work. This is the code I used (and the ComboBox still closes when I hit space)

```
public class ComboBoxAutoComplete<T> {

    private ComboBox<T> cmb;
    String filter = "";
    private ObservableList<T> originalItems;

    public ComboBoxAutoComplete(ComboBox<T> cmb) {
        this.cmb = cmb;

        ComboBoxListViewSkin<T> comboBoxListViewSkin = new ComboBoxListViewSkin<T>(cmb);
        comboBoxListViewSkin.getPopupContent().addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY, (event) -> {
            if( event.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE ) {
                event.consume();
            }
        });
        cmb.setSkin(comboBoxListViewSkin);

        originalItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList(cmb.getItems());
        cmb.setTooltip(new Tooltip());
        cmb.setOnKeyPressed(this::handleOnKeyPressed);
        cmb.setOnHidden(this::handleOnHiding);


    }

    public void handleOnKeyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        ObservableList<T> filteredList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        KeyCode code = e.getCode();

        ComboBoxListViewSkin<T> comboBoxListViewSkin = new ComboBoxListViewSkin<T>(cmb);
        comboBoxListViewSkin.getPopupContent().addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY, (event) -> {
            if( event.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE ) {
                event.consume();
            }
        });
        cmb.setSkin(comboBoxListViewSkin);


        if (code.isLetterKey()||code.isDigitKey()) {
            filter += e.getText();
        }
        if (code == KeyCode.BACK_SPACE && filter.length() > 0) {
            filter = filter.substring(0, filter.length() - 1);
            cmb.getItems().setAll(originalItems);
        }
        if (code == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
            filter = "";
        }
        if (filter.length() == 0) {
            filteredList = originalItems;
            cmb.getTooltip().hide();
        } else {
            Stream<T> itens = cmb.getItems().stream();
            String txtUsr = unaccent(filter.toString().toLowerCase());
            itens.filter(el -> unaccent(el.toString().toLowerCase()).contains(txtUsr)).forEach(filteredList::add);
            cmb.getTooltip().setText(txtUsr);
            Window stage = cmb.getScene().getWindow();
            double posX = stage.getX() + cmb.getBoundsInParent().getMinX();
            double posY = stage.getY() + cmb.getBoundsInParent().getMinY();
            cmb.getTooltip().show(stage, posX, posY);
            cmb.show();
        }
        cmb.getItems().setAll(filteredList);
    }



    public void handleOnHiding(Event e) {
        ComboBoxListViewSkin<T> comboBoxListViewSkin = new ComboBoxListViewSkin<T>(cmb);
        comboBoxListViewSkin.getPopupContent().addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY, (event) -> {
            if( event.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE ) {
                event.consume();
            }
        });
        cmb.setSkin(comboBoxListViewSkin);
        filter = "";
        cmb.getTooltip().hide();
        T s = cmb.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        cmb.getItems().setAll(originalItems);
        cmb.getSelectionModel().select(s);
    }

    private String unaccent(String s) {
        ComboBoxListViewSkin<T> comboBoxListViewSkin = new ComboBoxListViewSkin<T>(cmb);
        comboBoxListViewSkin.getPopupContent().addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY, (event) -> {
            if( event.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE ) {
                event.consume();
            }
        });
        cmb.setSkin(comboBoxListViewSkin);
        String temp = Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+");
        return pattern.matcher(temp).replaceAll("");
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent closing of AutoCompleteCombobox popupmenu on SPACE key press in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50013972/how-to-prevent-closing-of-autocompletecombobox-popupmenu-on-space-key-press-in-j)

Comment: the question is answered, so this is a duplicate and will be closed. If you have a problem with the answer, be specific in what you don't understand (though it can't ge much simpler - override the combo's skin and let your combo return your version as default)

Comment: kleopatra, I saw that answer, but it either doesn't work and/or I am not smart enough to figure out how to use it. This is the code I tried (and when I hit 'space' the ComboBox still closes!):

Comment: looks like you need to learn a bit more about skins and how/when they are instantiated .. instead of setting them again and again, override createDefaultSkin to return the custom one (with the bug hack)

Comment: K, so this falls squarely under the column of "I am not smart enough to figure out how to use it" . Thank you.

Comment: no, it falls under the category "the problem is solved by a custom skin, you have to learn how to create a control with a custom skin" - which is a different question ;) And even that is answered in my last comment, just do it ...