# JavaFX Autocomplete ComboBox using JavaFX virtual Keyboard

Tags: javafx, combobox, keyboard, virtual, autofill

For this you can refer to this question:

[AutoComplete ComboBox in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924852/autocomplete-combobox-in-javafx)

I was able to get this working using both the FxUtilTest class example and the AutoCompleteComboBoxListener class example. In both cases this works fine with an actual keyboard. However it does not autocomplete when entering text through the JavaFX virtual keyboard.

I figured the key events do not work with that virtual keyboard. I tried adding a change listener to the ComboBox when the text changes then applied the same functionality for autofilling. That didn't seem to work as expected. Has anyone ran into this issue before? Are there other events I should look to add to a class to allow a ComboBox to autofill from the virtual keyboard?

Comment: Post a small sample app that demos what you tried to do.