# When should a JavaFX Combo Box trigger its onAction?

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I have a JavaFX Combo Box where, once an item is selected,  another combo box is populated with a list of relevant items.  So I've set onAction for my Combo Box to be `handleSelect()` and this is the function that takes care of populating the second combo box.

When should `handleSelect()` be triggered?  When I select an item from the combo box, `handleSelect()` is triggered as expected.  However, `handleSelect()` is also triggered when I click on the second combo box, even though that second combo box has no onAction set.  Additionally, `handleSelect()` is triggered when I click away to another window.

Is this the expected behavior of an onAction for a JavaFX combo box?

Incidentally, this used to work and now it doesn't and I don't know why.  Here's the code...

I have two comboBoxes, one called comboVariable and one called comboOperator.  When a variable is selected from comboVariable, the comboOperator box is populated with relational operators that make sense for the variable type selected.  To do this I've created a class called UserVariable and an enum type RelationOperator.

```
@FXML ComboBox<ComboBoxItem<String>> comboVariable;
@FXML ComboBox<SimpleConditional.RelationalOperator> comboOperator;

public void initWindow()
{
    setContents();
}

public void setContents()
{
    System.out.println("setContents called");
    comboVariable.getItems().clear();
    if (getVars().size() > 0) {
        for(Map.Entry<String, UserVariable<? extends Comparable<?>>> varEntry : getVars().entrySet()) {
            comboVariable.getItems().add(new ComboBoxItem<String>(varEntry.getKey(), true));
        }
    }

    // make comboVariable autocomplete
    FxUtil.autoCompleteComboBox(comboVariable, 
            (typedText, itemToCompare) -> itemToCompare.getName().toLowerCase().contains(typedText.toLowerCase()) 
    );
}

@FXML public void handleSelect()
// This method is called whenever a variable name is selected in the comboVariable combobox
{
    System.out.println("handleSelectVar called");

    ComboBoxItem<String> selectedItem = FxUtil.getComboBoxValue(comboVariable);

    if (selectedItem == null) return;

    String varName = selectedItem.getName();

    UserVariable<?> selectedVar = getVar(varName);
    if (selectedVar == null) return;

    myVarType = selectedVar.getType();

    setComboAndLabelBasedOnType();
}

private void setComboAndLabelBasedOnType()
// This helper function is called by handleSelect()
// It sets the available operators to be == and != for Strings and Bool and makes all operators available for
// Doubles and Integers.
{
    System.out.println("setComboAndLabelBasedOnType called");

    comboOperator.getItems().clear();

    switch (myVarType) {
    case STRING:
    case BOOL:
        comboOperator.getItems().addAll(RelationalOperator.EQ, RelationalOperator.NE);
        break;
    case DOUBLE:
    case INT:
        comboOperator.getItems().addAll(RelationalOperator.EQ, RelationalOperator.NE, 
                RelationalOperator.GT, RelationalOperator.GE, RelationalOperator.LT, 
                RelationalOperator.LE);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the code of both Comboboxes and how you fill them.

Comment: Question updated to include code

Comment: I am not familiar with `FxUtil` but I suspect it may be firing the `ComboBox` at different times as part of the apparent auto-complete functionality. I would recommend adding a listener to the `comboVariable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()` instead of using `setOnAction()` anyway.

Comment: @Zephyr You were right, it was the autocomplete that was causing problems.  I commented that part out and it works as expected.  I got the autocomplete combo box implementation from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924852/autocomplete-combobox-in-javafx  Perhaps that solution doesn't work with Java 10 and later (which is roughly when this problem first appeared)

Comment: That solution calls `setEditable(false)` in a number of places, the ComboBox documentation states that when set to false, the selected value is cleared and the actions are fired, hence the second call.  I think Zephyr and I had the same comments on the other post.