# Addlistener to "autocomplete" Combobox in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, javafx-8

I implemented a ComboBox which is editable and autocompletes itself similar to the one in this answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27384068/9611276

Now i want to add a listener which performs some action when the value in this Combobox changes. Something like this:

```
combobox.getValueProperty().addListener((obs, oldV, newV) -> {...});
```

The problem is, that i cannot access the combobox.getValueProperty() without getting a **java.lang.ClassCastException**. In the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27384068/9611276) above it is mentioned to **get** the combobox value with the following function:

```
    public static <T> TgetComboBoxValue(ComboBox<T> comboBox) {
    if (comboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() < 0) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return comboBox.getItems().get(comboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
    }
}
```

How do i create and access the property to add a listener?

Thanks, 
BR

Comment: To be honest, I tried the "answer" to that question and there were many serious bugs that I couldn't continue with it. I provided in my opinion a much better solution based on some of the other answers in there whilst fixing some of its bugs. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55709876/9278333  I have it in a production environment and it is working extremely well (even with 10,000+ possible values). There is also a path forward to Java 9+ once you upgrade.

Answer (score -2):

You can add a propertyChangeListener to that combobox

```
 comboBox.addPropertyChangeListener(evt -> {

 });
```

Or additionally, you can fire your own property change event. Where 2 is the old value and 3 is the new value of combobox. It can take strings, booleans and other primitive types too.

```
 comboBox.firePropertyChange("samplePropertyChange", 2, 3);
```

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about JavaFX here?

Comment: I think he is in the Swing world